# Windows Phone MVVM Login Page design pattern?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create a login page where the users enters username/password then a web service authenticates and saves an authentication token retrieved from the server.

I want the page view to be notified when the authentication is done successfully.

my question is: how to implement this in MVVM pattern ? I created a class for the model, a class for the model view and a class for the calling and parsing of the web service.

I can't set my **ModelView** as a **DataContext** for the page cause there are no controls that bind to the Model's data.

is this pattern an overkill or it can be implemented in another way ? please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a login page that is implemented as [described here](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/06/18/Using-a-custom-UriMapper-to-navigate-to-a-login-screen.aspx). The login page itself does not have a viewmodel, but it does use a service that I wrote that contains a callback when the login completes. the service also contains other useful info about the user. I think MVVM would have been overkill here.

```
    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailTextBox.Text)) return;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordTextBox.Password)) return;

        Login();
    }

    private void Login()
    {
        if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I'm having trouble connecting to the internet." + Environment.NewLine + "Make sure you have cell service or are connected to WiFi then try again");
        }
        else
        {
            LoginButton.Focus(); // Removes the keyboard
            UserProfile.Name = EmailTextBox.Text;
            UserProfile.Password = PasswordTextBox.Password;

            UserProfile.Current.Login(result =>
                {
                    // callback could be on another thread
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            // Did the login succeed?
                            if (result.Result)
                            {
                                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string message = "Sorry, but I was not able to log in that user. Please make sure the name and password were entered correctly.";
                                MessageBox.Show(message, "Login failed");
                            }
                        });
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `ICommand`s in your ViewModel that point to methods who perform calls your web service, and the elements in your View should bind to those commands to perform actions.

And you need one more boolean property in your viewmodel: IsLoggedIn, that you set to true when the Login call to your webservice returns a success.

Then in your view, you can bind to IsLoggedIn to give feedback to your users.

Note: don't forget to raise PropertyChanged for IsLoggedIn in its setter.